# Best way to migrate single project from Jira 5.0 to Jira 8?

Tags: jira, data-migration

I want to move a single project from a Jira 5.0 instance to a new Jira 8.0 instance being already used for other projects - so the process must not bring in configurations, workflows, etc. nor should alter existing projects.

I'm only interested in importing issues and related data:

- title, description, etc (obviously)
- attachments (images, files, whatever)
- issue links
- issue type (with mapping to new types in case they don't match)
- ... (other properties that I'm forgetting right now)

I've just started searching for the topic and already found several options - and it's not clear if they're all available to be, mosly due to the starting Jira version, they are:

- Export to CSV and import to CSV
- Export to XML
- [Import from JSON](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/import-data-from-json/) (though I've yet to find a JSON export)
- Rest API
- [Import project from backup](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA050/Restoring+a+Project+from+Backup)
- ... and surely others

Of course I'd like the most complete yet less error-prone method, though if resorting to the REST API will be the only way to be sure to import all I want, I'm ready to write a script / program.

So, what should I choose?

P.S.: I'm not sure if this fits this community, is there a more proper one?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get csv export, get all attachments (jira_home/data/attachments). Then copy attachments to a new instance to jira_home/import. You'll need to edit export file to match names and paths of your attachments in order to import them successfully.
And last step is import csv to your Jira 8 instance.
I suggest trying this on dev/stage environment first because there are many small details that can affect import.

Some useful data is here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/importing-data-from-csv-938847533.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. "I suggest trying this on dev/stage environment first because there are many small details that can affect import." this scares me a little as we only have a single production instance already being used, I'll keep your warning in mind.

Comment: It doesn't take a lot of time to set up your own local jira instance (it can use embedded database) and probably it will eventually save your time. I was administrating Jira for 1.5 years and almost all imports from different instances were done on stage first. Even one misprint or blank space can affect the import.